# dojo show map cordinates on mouse click

Tags: jquery, dojo, cross-browser, gis

Im new and throwing some things together to begin a web based map for our department.  I have checked all major browsers.  I cant find any errors or get the points to show up.  Whats wrong with this script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>
  Your Cool Page With an AGRC Base Map
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.1/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.1">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("esri.map");
     var map = {}

     var Init = function () {              
     map = new esri.Map("map", { logo: false });              
     var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(                    
     "http://mapserv.utah.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/UtahBaseMap-Hybrid/MapServer", 
     { id: "Hybrid" });              map.addLayer(layer);          };
     dojo.ready(Init);    

dojo.connect("map", "onClick", function(evt){ 
//get mapPoint from event and display the mouse coordinates 
var mp = evt.mapPoint; 
dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = mp.x + ", " + mp.y; 
    alert(mp.x);
}); 


</script>
   </head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="map"></div>
<p id="info">
  a
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant see your reference to the dojo.js, could you copy and paste the actual source that is giving an error?

Comment: This line is the one that links to dojo. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.1"> </script>    In my question above i say -- I cant find any errors or get the points to show up. -- firebug shows no errors, ie shows no errors.  The map does show and you can pan and zoom at will however the onclick event to get the points is not functioning.

Comment: the dojo.connect should go inside the the ready function at the very end, also you need to use the variable map in the "connect" function, instead of the string map.  that makes the onClick event work, other than that, I can't see another problem

Comment: @RicardoGarzaV. Post that as your answer and i will give you the credit.  That fixed it.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @user1015711 could you post the working code, please? I'm also interested in something similar. Thanks! :)